# How do I display the facebook wall posts on the website without user to login?

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on the .net website project that aggregate multiple sources of Facebook account wall posts. I'm able to get the access token to use for the graph API calls but I need the way to do this without user logging in to the Facebook or at least it needs be done behind the scene.

According to the Facebook doc, I have to give the choice to the user to authorize my app, is it possible to skip this process or what is the best practice to do this?

Thanks

**Update**

I finally use App Login Method by just follow the document:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

This allow me to get access token without user authorize my app.

Answer (score 1):

Request the `offline_access` permission when the user authorizes your application. You can then use this token to make requests even if the user is not currently online.

You cannot skip the initial authorization - this is a requirement of Facebook.