# How to amend my code to get FB users posts, not my own?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Currently, I am able to get all posts made on my Facebook page, **by me only** (using PHP). How can I adjust this to bring in posts from other users on my Facebook page?

If that is an easy one, can I also **only display posts** that include "Racing Car" text in their post?

Thanks

PHP as follows:

```
switch (type) {
        case "facebook":
            var cp = id.split("/");
            url = url = cp.length > 1 ? "https://graph.facebook.com/" + cp[1] + "/photos?fields=id,link,from,name,picture,images,comments&limit=" +
                n : frl + encodeURIComponent("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=" + id + "&format=rss20");
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use access token(i case if you want to post to user wall even if user is not active in facebook) of the user to whom you want to see or post to facebook wall.You need to combine userId and access token.If the user is currently using the app then you don't need access token.[Post automatically on the wall of user (facebook App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999806/post-automatically-on-the-wall-of-user-facebook-app)

Comment: Thanks @MadanRam but I am not using an app so to speak. I would like to use the access_token to displays all user posts from our Facebook page on our website. Then I would like to only display the posts on our facebook page from users that contain a certain string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386497/how-do-i-display-the-facebook-wall-posts-on-the-website-without-user-to-login you need access token so , what you can do is to ask user to authorize as app and then display in website.

Comment: Don't want to have the authorisation, it's not an app. The posts are public information - can use search but it doesn't work well https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/